# content node Structure needs cleaning?

Tags: vespa

I have two content node, one will show the above error message, how can i fix this ?

i am so confuse that i cannot deploy my app !

the stackoverflow show me this !
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
oh my god, i don't know what to write

```
[2022-08-04 14:55:22.329] WARNING : metricsproxy-container stderr       com.yahoo.jdisc.application.BundleInstallationException: Unable to cache bundle: file:/opt/vespa/lib/jars/asm-tree-9.2.jar
[2022-08-04 14:55:22.329] WARNING : metricsproxy-container stderr       \tat com.yahoo.jdisc.core.FelixFramework.installBundle(FelixFramework.java:90)
[2022-08-04 14:55:22.329] WARNING : metricsproxy-container stderr       \tat com.yahoo.jdisc.core.ApplicationLoader.init(ApplicationLoader.java:118)
[2022-08-04 14:55:22.329] WARNING : metricsproxy-container stderr       \tat com.yahoo.jdisc.core.StandaloneMain.run(StandaloneMain.java:43)
[2022-08-04 14:55:22.329] WARNING : metricsproxy-container stderr       \tat com.yahoo.jdisc.core.StandaloneMain.main(StandaloneMain.java:34)
[2022-08-04 14:55:22.329] WARNING : metricsproxy-container stderr       Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to cache bundle: file:/opt/vespa/lib/jars/asm-tree-9.2.jar
[2022-08-04 14:55:22.329] WARNING : metricsproxy-container stderr       \tat org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.installBundle(Felix.java:3258)
[2022-08-04 14:55:22.329] WARNING : metricsproxy-container stderr       \tat org.apache.felix.framework.BundleContextImpl.installBundle(BundleContextImpl.java:147)
[2022-08-04 14:55:22.329] WARNING : metricsproxy-container stderr       \tat org.apache.felix.framework.BundleContextImpl.installBundle(BundleContextImpl.java:120)
[2022-08-04 14:55:22.329] WARNING : metricsproxy-container stderr       \tat com.yahoo.jdisc.core.FelixFramework.installBundle(FelixFramework.java:186)
[2022-08-04 14:55:22.329] WARNING : metricsproxy-container stderr       \tat com.yahoo.jdisc.core.FelixFramework.installBundle(FelixFramework.java:196)
[2022-08-04 14:55:22.329] WARNING : metricsproxy-container stderr       \tat com.yahoo.jdisc.core.FelixFramework.installBundle(FelixFramework.java:88)
[2022-08-04 14:55:22.329] WARNING : metricsproxy-container stderr       \t... 3 more
[2022-08-04 14:55:22.329] WARNING : metricsproxy-container stderr       Caused by: java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /opt/vespa/var/jdisc_container/f6caf3dba440ed3dedb384a9fb811435/bundlecache/felix-cache/bundle37/version0.0/bundle.jar: Structure needs cleaning
[2022-08-04 14:55:22.329] WARNING : metricsproxy-container stderr       \tat java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:100)
[2022-08-04 14:55:22.329] WARNING : metricsproxy-container stderr       \tat java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:111)
[2022-08-04 14:55:22.329] WARNING : metricsproxy-container stderr       \tat java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:116)
[2022-08-04 14:55:22.329] WARNING : metricsproxy-container stderr       \tat java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:219)
[2022-08-04 14:55:22.329] WARNING : metricsproxy-container stderr       \tat java.base/java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newOutputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:478)
[2022-08-04 14:55:22.329] WARNING : metricsproxy-container stderr       \tat java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newOutputStream(Files.java:220)
[2022-08-04 14:55:22.329] WARNING : metricsproxy-container stderr       \tat org.apache.felix.framework.util.SecureAction.getOutputStream(SecureAction.java:555)
[2022-08-04 14:55:22.329] WARNING : metricsproxy-container stderr       \tat org.apache.felix.framework.cache.BundleCache.copyStreamToFile(BundleCache.java:545)
[2022-08-04 14:55:22.329] WARNING : metricsproxy-container stderr       \tat org.apache.felix.framework.cache.JarRevision.initialize(JarRevision.java:170)
[2022-08-04 14:55:22.329] WARNING : metricsproxy-container stderr       \tat org.apache.felix.framework.cache.JarRevision.<init>(JarRevision.java:76)
[2022-08-04 14:55:22.329] WARNING : metricsproxy-container stderr       \tat org.apache.felix.framework.cache.BundleArchive.createRevisionFromLocation(BundleArchive.java:819)
[2022-08-04 14:55:22.329] WARNING : metricsproxy-container stderr       \tat org.apache.felix.framework.cache.BundleArchive.reviseInternal(BundleArchive.java:491)
[2022-08-04 14:55:22.329] WARNING : metricsproxy-container stderr       \tat org.apache.felix.framework.cache.BundleArchive.<init>(BundleArchive.java:155)
[2022-08-04 14:55:22.330] WARNING : metricsproxy-container stderr       \tat org.apache.felix.framework.cache.BundleCache.create(BundleCache.java:456)
[2022-08-04 14:55:22.330] WARNING : metricsproxy-container stderr       \tat org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.installBundle(Felix.java:3254)
[2022-08-04 14:55:22.330] WARNING : metricsproxy-container stderr       \t... 8 more
[2022-08-04 14:55:22.334] INFO    : config-sentinel  sentinel.sentinel.service  metricsproxy-container: incremented restart penalty to 510.000 seconds
[2022-08-04 14:55:22.334] INFO    : config-sentinel  sentinel.sentinel.service  metricsproxy-container: will delay start by 508.938 seconds
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like Vespa cannot write to /opt/vespa/var/jdisc_container/f6caf3dba440ed3dedb384a9fb811435/bundlecache/felix-cache/bundle37/version0.0/bundle.jar - so something wrong with permissions of the file system / disk full?

As this is a cache, you can try to remove everything under bundlecache and see if it helps

Comment: not work , log is too long, so i post an answer instead of "add comment", please help, thanks